# How to send data with email using combo box and radio buttons in outlook 2013 forms

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am new in Outlook custom forms. I am working with Outlook 2013. I have work to create a form with 4 drop downs, 2 radio buttons and 1 text box. I designed the form properly using developer tools in Outlook, but when I send the mail after running the form no data is sent with the mail that I typed in the TextBox. The second problem is that I have no idea how I can set the value in ComboBoxes and RadioButtons and send them with mail.

Comment: Did you associate controls with corresponding user properties?

Comment: I have only drag and drop controls in message custom form as snap shot:    http://snag.gy/ZAOsx.jpg

Comment: Are you assigning a value to the mail item property `Body` or `HtmlBody`?  Both are strings so transferring values from a ComboBox should be easy although if you use `HtmlBody` you will have to surround the text with an Html envelope.  By "Radio Button" do you mean what Microsoft forms calls "Option Button"?  What about the Option Button do you wish to transfer to the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate custom controls with user properties that may contain values between sessions. See [Customizing Outlook Message Forms](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=61) for more information.